# How to modify quantity on checkout confirm step in opencart 2.1.0.2 version?

Tags: php, opencart2.x

I am using opencart version 2.1.0.2, I wants to modify quantity of product before click on confirm button on checkout page.

Currently on opencart checkout step-6 confirm display only quantity of product, but how can I modify quantity there as same as cart page.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You would need to write a core modification for the last checkout process step. Currently the last step (confirmation) is only the display of your entered products and their amounts.

I would not recommend changing the amount of a product at this stage. Why would you do so? Is changing the quantity in the basket not enough? Most commerce systems display a summary at the end of the checkout process. Why can't you keep with this "almost" standard?

Comment: Yes sir, you are right, but if customer wants to modify the quantity of product then, he has to go to cart page. I want to provide minimal step to customer.thats why

Comment: Still I would not recommend this because this step is used to verify the customers choices. If you would let him change the quantity here I think you need to implementiert another step after that one showing the final summary before ordering. So this would be a lot of work for IMHO no real improvement.